# Django: Confused about backwards relations in views

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have object **CarMaker**:

```
class CarMaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And object **CarModel** stored in variable **car_inst**:

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    maker = models.ForeignKey(CarMaker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    serial_number   = models.CharField(max_length=50)

car_inst = CarModel.objects.get(id=foo)
```

I need to get the **CarMaker** that "owns" it.

I tried with:

```
maker = CarMaker.objects.get(id__in=car_inst.id)
```

This doesn't work. I've seen examples online of using backwards relations along the lines of:

```
maker = carmaker.carmodel_set.all()
```

But that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Whats wrong with `maker.carmodel_set.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get maker of `car_inst` you can just use `car_inst.maker`.
Reverse relations using in case you need to get list of cars related with specific maker `maker.carmodel_set.all()` this will give you all car models of the selected maker.

Comment: Damnit I forgot about this. Sometimes the brain turns to mush. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it step by step:

Get the `CarModel` object for which you want the `CarMaker` for :

```
car_model = CarModel.objects.get(id=foo)
```

Now, let us get the `CarMaker` associated with this object:

```
car_maker = car_model.maker
```